# Application does not render "PrimeFaces" components

Tags: jsf, primefaces

My JSF application does not render "PrimeFaces components". I have seen many topics about these problem but none helped me.

Here are my artefacts:

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.jsf.wcanatto.loja_games</groupId>
    <artifactId>loja_games</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>loja_games Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>



    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>loja_games</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>  

  <!-- JSF mapping -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>



<!-- Map these files with JSF -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

index.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>Hello World PrimeFaces</h1>

    <h:form>
       <p:editor value="test" />
    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

When I acces the page from browser the "primefaces" componentes are not showed.

Comment: But what DOES happen? Source code shown?

Comment: does not have happen anything (anything was printed at log), the components simply doesn`t are shown.

Comment: Aren't shown means client side there is **nothing** in the browser developer tool when looking at the source of the page? Or is `<p:editor.../>` shown there? In that case something **does** happen, namely that the tags are not interpreted server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primefaces 3.4.2 is not JSF 2.2 compatible. Change `jsf-impl` and `jsf-api` to use version 2.1 instead and also change `web.xml` to use version 2.5 dtd.

Change JSF version in pom.xml :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.19</version>
    </dependency>
```

Update web.xml to version 2.5 and turn on JSF development mode

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Better to suggest to update PrimeFaces to a recent version

Comment: Updating to latest version is indeed a solution but not necessary better depending on the project setup and application server used.

Comment: Which application server are you using?

Comment: apache-tomcat-7.0.39

Comment: I took your code and after applying the changes, the primefaces component loaded properly when run on tomcat 7. I'll add the details of the changes.

Comment: – Dukefirehawk, thanks for your help, but it does not work for me. My projet are host in github (https://github.com/filipecanatto/vale_a_pena_jogar). Could you see the project and try to search the bug?, then could you commit the changes pls. I alredy try everything but it does not work.

Comment: Your code in github is working fine when deployed to `apache-tomcat-7.0.56`. The compiled war file can be found under `dist` folder at https://github.com/dukefirehawk/vale_a_pena_jogar a fork of your repository. Test url used  is http://localhost:8080/loja_games/index.faces.

Comment: Dukefirehawk, thanks a milion man, now are running very well. Thanks for spend your time to help  me.

Comment: I think the problem was in to use eclipse IDE, when I deployed from maven and make the deploy manually in server, the primefaces componentes have been shown.